# Android : file error Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, file-handling

I have stored the file to the External storage and does the read / write operation with this file. The file is created, and data also get stored but the every time I encounter into exception that is :

- java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/sdcard0/info.dcini: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
- Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

My code :

```
try 
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    File rootFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    rootFile.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(rootFile.getAbsolutePath(), MASTER_FILE_NAME);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
           stringBuilder.append(line);
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Can anyone point out the why the exception is there ?

EDIT :

The Code that creates file and write to file is :

```
try 
{
    File rootFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    rootFile.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(rootFile.getAbsolutePath(), MASTER_FILE_NAME);
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
    out.write("my string data");
    out.close();
}
catch(Exception e)  
{
}
```

Comment: If you log both the result of rootFile.getAbsolutePath() and MASTER_FILE_NAME separately, what do you get? What is the file on the sdcard itself called (go into shell / explorer and look yourself, to make sure)?

Comment: if you add if(file.exists()) what happens?

Comment: why You are doing rootFile.mkdirs(); ? It´s the external storage directory....you don´t need this..

Comment: You should provide the code where You store the file...

Comment: How are your verifying that "The file is created, and data also get store" ?  That seems rather doubtful, or at least, the file which is created is not the one you are trying to open.

Comment: @Knossos the details are : rootFile = "/storage/sdcard0", MASTER_FILE_NAME = "info.txt", file = "/storage/sdcard0/info.txt". In explorer I can see the info.txt file with my data

Comment: How was the file created, by your App?

Comment: Yes, when I debug then i got exception at line : BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); Here is the code that creates the file : File rootFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            rootFile.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(rootFile.getAbsolutePath(), MASTER_FILE_NAME);
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
            out.write(packageName);
            out.close();

Comment: What is "explorer" ? that you are using to verify the file?  Show the code which you believe creates it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton the "explorer" means any file explorer(e.g. ES File Explorer). I am able to see the file with its content.

Comment: You say you can see "info.txt" but your missing file error is for "info.dcini"

Comment: @ChrisStratton, that was the typo error sorry for that, later I changed the "info.dcini" to "info.txt" , to open it through the file explorer and see the contents into it.